# How can I place a button in the the tabs of a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

[image]I am using a Tabbed Page combined with a Master Detail Page for navigation in my Xamarin.Forms app. Currently when a menu option is selected from the Master Detail Page a new tabbed page is added with the page's content. I want to place a button to close the tab in the title field of the tab. Is this possible? Currently I just have a button within the content page for the tab, but this is less than ideal. I want it to be very web browser like. Thanks in advance!

Edit: I have added the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVFSq.png). Basically, I just want to add an "X" button to the right of each item in the tab bar that would allow me to close that tab. Just like you would in Chrome or something.

Comment: Can you show the picture what you want to do?

Comment: @YuriS I just added the image,

Comment: You showed what you have but not what you want, correct?

Comment: Correct. I just want to add the X to the right of what I already have. You can't see it, but there is master detail page that can be swept out from the left of the screen with all my menu options.

Comment: On Android tab you cannot even add an image to tab, so I can be wrong but I don't think it is possible what you want to do.

Comment: @YuriS thank you. I guess I'll just have to refine what I have

Comment: @user5661402, so you just want to place a button in each tab's title to close this tab? Nothing to do with `MasterDetailPage`? I think it definitely can be done.

Comment: @Grace-Feng - MSFT yes, the MasterDetailPage is kind of irrelevant. It's just where I get the pages to add to the TabbedPage. Do you know how to go about it?

Comment: @user5661402, yes, I just completed my demo and it works, wait a moment, I will now begin to answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use custom renderer to create your custom `TabbedPage` in android platform. Disagree with Yuri, on android we can add an image to tab, in fact we can customize the layout of tab.

Since in your image, I saw you didn't use the `Icon` property for each tab, I use this icon as a close button. **But** sure you can also not use this, it is self customized.

In PCL, create a `MyTabbedPage`:

```
public class MyTabbedPage : TabbedPage
{
}
```

In Android platform create a renderer for it:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(MyTabbedPage), typeof(MyTabbedPageRenderer))]

namespace YOURNAMESPACE.Droid
{
    public class MyTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Xamarin.Forms.Element> children;
        private IPageController controller;

        protected override void SetTabIcon(TabLayout.Tab tab, FileImageSource icon)
        {
            base.SetTabIcon(tab, icon);

            tab.SetCustomView(Resource.Layout.mytablayout);

            var imagebtn = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.closebtn);
            imagebtn.SetBackgroundDrawable(tab.Icon);

            var title = tab.CustomView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tabtitle);
            title.Text = tab.Text;

            imagebtn.Click += (sender, e) =>
            {
                var closebtn = sender as ImageButton;
                var parent = closebtn.Parent as Android.Widget.RelativeLayout;
                var closingtitle = parent.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tabtitle);
                foreach (var child in children)
                {
                    var page = child as ContentPage;
                    if (page.Title == closingtitle.Text)
                    {
                        children.Remove(child);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                controller = Element as IPageController;
                children = controller.InternalChildren;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
<local:MyTabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TabbedPageForms"
             x:Class="TabbedPageForms.MainPage">

    <local:TodayPage Title="Today" Icon="hamburger.jpg" />

    <local:SchedulePage Title="Schedule" Icon="hamburger.jpg" />
</local:MyTabbedPage>
```

Code behind, don't forget to change `MainPage` to inherit from `MyTabbedPage`:

```
public partial class MainPage : MyTabbedPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

[image]

**Please pay attention here**, if you look closer to my code, you will find that I used `Title` of each tab for the comparing and removing the matching item, it will find the first matched title and remove the page of that title. This may cause a problem if you have several tabs with the same title. This is a potential bug of this demo, you may try to solve it.

Update:

Forgot to post the code of `mytablayout`, here is it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView android:id="@+id/tabtitle"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

  <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/closebtn"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:gravity="center" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, where did you place the __mytablayout__ file? And is it __.axml__?

Comment: @user5661402, in android platform's layout folder, yes, it's axml.

Comment: Okay, so I have the file in the Android platform in Resources/layout/mytablayout.axml, but it keeps saying that 'Resources does not contain a definition for layout and no extension method layout accepting a first argument of type Resources could be found'

Really sorry if I'm asking too much.

Comment: @user5661402, have you saved the .axml file, looks like the resource is not generated, try to clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: I fixed it. There was a using statement that was causing the wrong Resource to be pulled.

Comment: How can I change font size of title. Because small device truncate the title of page.