# Xamarin Forms change the tabbar size

Tags: c#, android, forms, xamarin

Im having trouble with the text size of my Tabbar on Forms.Droid.

It looks like this:
[image]

Does anyone know how to make the fontsize smaller, thus fixing this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Custom Renderers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/) to create your renderer for `TabbedPage`, and then in the renderer you can code for example like this:

```
public class StyledTabbedPageRenderer : TabbedPageRenderer
{
    private Android.Views.View formViewPager = null;
    private TabLayout tabLayout = null;

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<TabbedPage> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        this.tabLayout = (TabLayout)this.GetChildAt(1);

        changeTabsFont();
    }

    private void changeTabsFont()
    {
        //Typeface font = Typeface.CreateFromAsset(Android.App.Application.Context.Assets, "fonts/" + Constants.FontStyle);
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup)tabLayout.GetChildAt(0);
        int tabsCount = vg.ChildCount;
        for (int j = 0; j < tabsCount; j++)
        {
            ViewGroup vgTab = (ViewGroup)vg.GetChildAt(j);
            int tabChildsCount = vgTab.ChildCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < tabChildsCount; i++)
            {
                Android.Views.View tabViewChild = vgTab.GetChildAt(i);
                if (tabViewChild is TextView)
                {
                    //((TextView)tabViewChild).Typeface = font;
                    ((TextView)tabViewChild).TextSize = 6;

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can also refer to my other case about customize `TabbedPage`:

[How can I place a button in the the tabs of a TabbedPage in Xamarin.Forms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507091/how-can-i-place-a-button-in-the-the-tabs-of-a-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms/44511454#44511454)

Comment: I have implement this, but My Tabbar Render at top, while I have customize it at bottom, How can I change the position in Custom Renderer?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to custom style and change size of text in the tab.

Something like:

```
<style name="MyTab" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
    <item name="android:textSize"></item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried this and referenced this style in my TabBar.axml file but it does not seem to work. I put 5px for the text size and the text size stayed the same, same happens when I put 100px..