# Hide the label of the TabbedPage selected item on Android or Resize Label text

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

i'm having some troubles with tabbedpage, the request from my customer is to show all the labels in tabbedpage items, but as you can see in the print the labels doesn't fit right

[image: Print1]

[image: Print2]

[image: Goal]

The goal is to fit all the labels like in third printscreen or Hide the selected item label only.

PS: i'm using an custom effect to disable the tabbedpage shiftmode, here is the code:

```
[assembly: ResolutionGroupName("Fullware")]
[assembly: ExportEffect(typeof(NoShiftEffect), "NoShiftEffect")]
namespace SincorSPM.Droid
{
    public class NoShiftEffect : PlatformEffect
    {
        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            if (!(Container.GetChildAt(0) is ViewGroup layout))
                return;

            if (!(layout.GetChildAt(1) is BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView))
                return;

            // This is what we set to adjust if the shifting happens
            bottomNavigationView.LabelVisibilityMode = LabelVisibilityMode.LabelVisibilityLabeled;
        }



        protected override void OnDetached()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Edit //

Requested TabbedPage XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            android:TabbedPage.IsSmoothScrollEnabled="True"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
            BarBackgroundColor="#032e5c"
            BarTextColor="#e27900"
            xmlns:lottie="clr-namespace:Lottie.Forms;assembly=Lottie.Forms"
            SelectedTabColor="#009fe2"
             xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:SincorSPM"
            xmlns:pancake="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.PancakeView"
             UnselectedTabColor="#e27900"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SincorSPM;assembly=SincorSPM"
             x:Class="SincorSPM.Main.TabbedMain">

   <TabbedPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Color x:Key="BackgroundColor">#032e5c</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ButtonColor">#286d9f</Color>
            <Color x:Key="ButtonTextColor">#ffffff</Color>
            <Color x:Key="TitlesColor">#b99559</Color>

            <!-- Font Size -->

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </TabbedPage.Resources>
    <TabbedPage.Effects>
        <local:NoShiftEffect />
    </TabbedPage.Effects>

   //Content Pages

</TabbedPage>
```

Comment: Could you share the xaml code or a sample just about tab , this will be helpful .

Comment: Ofc @JuniorJiang-MSFT, i'll update the question

Comment: Possible solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46536380/8395242

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Xamarin Forms change the tabbar size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46513240/xamarin-forms-change-the-tabbar-size)

Comment: @GuilhermeNimer Thanks for updating . When selecting the tab bar , the size of font will not match . I think you can have a try with shared link to modify size of text first . If also has porblem , you can update in question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution from Montemagno blog, using Resources/value/dimens.xml i can change the text size in this way:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="design_bottom_navigation_active_text_size" tools:override="true">12sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

refer to [Montemagno Blog](https://montemagno.com/control-text-size-on-android-bottom-navigation/)