# Xamarin forms Add button in TabbedPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I have a question. I created the following TabbedPage:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MyApp.Views"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            x:Class="MyApp.Views.MainPage"
            xmlns:android="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.AndroidSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
            android:TabbedPage.ToolbarPlacement="Bottom"
            BarBackgroundColor="White"
            BarTextColor="Black"
            android:TabbedPage.BarItemColor="#B2B2B2"
            android:TabbedPage.BarSelectedItemColor="#56D7A5"
            android:TabbedPage.IsSwipePagingEnabled="False">    

    <TabbedPage.Children>
        <NavigationPage Title="page1" IconImageSource="navbar_page1">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:page1 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="page2" IconImageSource="navbar_page2">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:page2 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>

        <NavigationPage Title="page3" IconImageSource="navbar_page3">
            <x:Arguments>
                <views:page3 NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="False" />
            </x:Arguments>
        </NavigationPage>
    
</TabbedPage>
```

Now on every page I have added this custom FabMenu like this:

```
<c:FloatingMenu Margin="0, 0, 10, 10" BGColor="#56D7A5" OpenIcon="openFab_icon" CloseIcon="closeFab_icon"
                AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds=".95,.95" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional">
    <c:FloatingButton x:Name="btnAddHomework" BGColor="#59E1FF" IconSrc="add_homework_icon" OnClickCommand="{Binding btnAddHomeworkCommand}" />
    <c:FloatingButton x:Name="btnAddDeadline" BGColor="#0FF1A0" IconSrc="add_deadline_icon"/>
    <c:FloatingButton x:Name="btnAddTest" BGColor="#5988FF" IconSrc="add_test_icon"/>
</c:FloatingMenu>
```

The problem is that every page has his own FabMenu, so you see it dissapear and reappear on every page, so my question is: Is there some kind of root view that overlays all the tabs in the TabbedPage?

Please let me know how I do that!

Comment: I just want to say most of these replies are NOT true. Adding a BUTTON to a TABBED PAGE is POSSIBLE (although not easy, you could say) using custom renderers. Refer to this question: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44507091/how-can-i-place-a-button-in-the-the-tabs-of-a-tabbedpage-in-xamarin-forms)

Comment: I mean a button that doesn't disappear when you switch tabs, so an overlay for the tabs. The link is for a image inside the gabbar, but that is not what I mean

Comment: I think in your case ToolBarItem is a good workaround

Comment: It is most certainly possible. I recommend using a static instance of the FloatingMenu.

@LucasZhang-MSFT - As a fellow Microsoft employee, I highly recommend that you avoid saying something is "impossible" unless you know with 100% certainty that is cannot be done. A better response is "I am not aware how to achieve this" or no response at all.

We both represent Microsoft and the advice we give our fellow developers carries a lot of weight and will be received as truth.

Comment: Tabbed Page is a just a container of ContentPage you need to add the Floating Button on each ContentPage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Disclaimer

I came up with a way to create the effect wanted using only pure Xamarin.Forms. Read along and pay attention to the ***tricky*** parts of the solution.

### Abstract

This solution is achieved implementing `AbsoluteLayout`, `CarouselView`, `IndicatorView` and `DataTemplateSelector`. **Xamarin.Forms 4.8** is supposed in what follows. If a lower version is used, please take into account that features like `CarouselView` or `IndicatorView` could be in ***Preview*** status.

`DataTemplateSelector`, `CarouselView` and `IndicatorView` are used to simulate a `TabbedPage`, and `AbsoluteLayout` is used to provide the ***Overlay***.

So, now with the solution:

### Create your Views

Here you create a view for each of the pages you want. In this example i want my application to consist of two pages, so i create two views (code behind remains untouched):

**View1.xaml**

```xml
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="overlayTest.View1"
             BackgroundColor="Black">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms 1!"
                   TextColor="White"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

**View2.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="overlayTest.View2">
  <ContentView.Content>
      <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin.Forms 2!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" 
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
  </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

### Create a `DataTemplateSelector`

This will be used by the `CarouselView` in order to select one view or the other depending on the current `Position`.

```cs
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace overlayTest
{
    class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
    {

        readonly DataTemplate view1, view2;

        public MyTemplateSelector()
        {
            view1 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View1));
            view2 = new DataTemplate(typeof(View2));
        }

        protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
        {
            String s = item.ToString();
            if(s == "1")
            {
                return view1;
            }
            
            return view2;
        }
    }
}
```

### Create your Main Page

**Page1.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:t="clr-namespace:overlayTest"
             x:Class="overlayTest.Page1">
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <t:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="templateSelector"/>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     Padding="0"
                     Spacing="0">
                <CarouselView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
                          IndicatorView="indicatorView">
                    <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                        <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                            <x:String>1</x:String>
                            <x:String>2</x:String>
                        </x:Array>
                    </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
                </CarouselView>

                <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView">
                    <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                                <Frame Margin="10">
                                    <Label/>
                                </Frame>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
                </IndicatorView>

            </StackLayout>

            <ContentView 
                     IsVisible="True" VerticalOptions="Start"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                     AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                     BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Frame CornerRadius="10"
                   Margin="20"
                   VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand"
                   HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" InputTransparent="False">
                    <StackLayout Padding="0">
                        <Label 
                           FontSize="Medium"
                           TextColor="Black"/>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal"
                                 HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                            <Label Text="I am floating here"/>
                            <Switch IsToggled="True" />
                        </StackLayout>


                        <Button Text="Save"
                               BackgroundColor="Accent"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </ContentView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And in the code behind we set the name of the tabs. Here please put attention in the fact that i am supposing an element tree of a `StackLayout` -> `Frame` -> `Label`. If you change the `IndicatorTemplate`, you will have to also modify this part of the code!

**Page1.xaml.cs**

```cs
using System.Linq;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace overlayTest
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class Page1 : ContentPage
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            
            InitializeComponent();

            indicatorView.PropertyChanged += (s, a) =>
            {
                if (a.PropertyName == IndicatorView.HeightProperty.PropertyName)
                {
                    var indicators = indicatorView.IndicatorLayout.Children.ToList();

                    int counter = 0;

                    foreach(var indicator in indicators)
                    {
                        var indicatorBaseStack = (StackLayout)indicator;
                        var indicatorFrame = (Frame)indicatorBaseStack.Children[0];
                        var indicatorFrameLabel = (Label)indicatorFrame.Content;

                        indicatorFrameLabel.Text = counter == 0 ? "View1" : "View2";
                        counter++;
                    }
                }
            };

        }
    }

}
```

### Finally set that Page to the MainPage property of App:

```cs
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new Page1();
}
```

The final result looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could set **[ToolbarItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/toolbaritem#create-a-toolbaritem)** of each **ContentPage** (or you can define a base ContentPage).

```
<ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ToolbarItem Text="Example Item"
             IconImageSource="xxx.png"
             Order="Secondary"
             Clicked="{Binding xx}"
             Priority="0" />

    <ToolbarItem Text="Example Item"
             IconImageSource="xxx.png"
             Order="Secondary"
             Priority="1" />

    <ToolbarItem Text="Example Item"
             IconImageSource="xxx.png"
             Order="Secondary"
             Priority="2" />

</ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a `BaseContentPage` that includes a `static FloatingButton`. This allows every page to inherit from `BaseContentPage` and use the same `FloatingButton`.

### Code

**BaseContentPage**

```cs
abstract class BaseContentPage : ContentPage
{
    protected static Button Button { get; } = new Button { Text = $"This button was created at {DateTimeOffset.UtcNow}" }.Invoke(button => button.Clicked += HandleButtonClicked);

    static async void HandleButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        await Application.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Button Clicked", "This is the same button on both pages", "OK");
}
```

**Example LabelPage**

```cs
class LabelPage : BaseButtonPage
{
    public LabelPage()
    {
        Title = "LabelPage";

        Content = new StackLayout
        {
            Children =
            {
                new Label { Text = "Label Page" }.TextCenter().Center(),

                Button
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Example ButtonPage**

```cs
class ButtonPage : BaseButtonPage
{
    public ButtonPage()
    {
        Title = "ButtonPage";

        Content = Button;
    }
}
```

**Example App**

```cs
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        Device.SetFlags(new[] { "Markup_Experimental" });

        MainPage = new TabbedPage
        {
            Children =
            {
                new ButtonPage(),
                new LabelPage()
            }
        };
    }
}
```

### Sample App

Here is the sample app used to create the attached GIF:
https://github.com/brminnick/TabbedPageButton/

[image]

Comment: It does not float above the tabs, no. The button is shown inside of each ContentPage

Comment: Anything is possible . To clarify, you’re looking for a floating action button that will hover above the TabbedPage and is not individually added to each ContentPage?

Comment: Hi Brandon. I'm also looking for a way to display a view that will hover above the TabbedPage. I need it for display full screen Material Drawer since I'm unable to achieve same behavior with MasterDetailPage ☹️