# Xamarin Style IndicatorView to look like TabbedPage

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a problem. I recently had this problem: [Xamarin forms Add button in TabbedPage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64143533/xamarin-forms-add-button-in-tabbedpage), but that is fixed using the accepted anwser. In short, I am using a `CarouselView` and an `IndicatorView`, so I can have an overlay over multiple screens. Both the views replace my `TabbedPage`, but the `IndicatorView` needs to look like the `TabbedPageBar`. The only good page about styling an `IndicatorView` was this one: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/indicatorview.

Here is the page I have:

```
<StackLayout AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
            AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
            Padding="0"
            Spacing="0">

    <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView">
        <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Frame Margin="10">
                        <Label/>
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
    </IndicatorView>

    <CarouselView ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateSelector}"
                IndicatorView="indicatorView">
        <CarouselView.ItemsSource>
            <x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
                <x:String>1</x:String>
                <x:String>2</x:String>
                <x:String>3</x:String>
            </x:Array>
        </CarouselView.ItemsSource>
    </CarouselView>

</StackLayout>
```

Now how can I let the `IndicatorView` look like a `TabbedPageBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key point here is remove the `Shadow` and `CornerRadius` of `Frame`, then you can customize the layout in the Frame. Here is an example:

```
<IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" >
    <IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Spacing="0">
                <Frame  HasShadow="False" CornerRadius="0">
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Image Source="Images"/>
                        <Label Text="123" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                    </StackLayout>
                </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </IndicatorView.IndicatorTemplate>
</IndicatorView>
```